# XMPPFramework error in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xmppframework, bitcode

I installed pod 'XMPPFramework' in my project.
When I installed  pod asked  to Enable Bitcode " $ (inherited) and I did.
The installation of pod ' XMPPFramework ' is successful. But, I have one problem.
I already installed pod ' SWIFTHttp' in my project, that pod need to Enable Bitcode (YES).
But pod ' XMPPFramework' need to Enable Bitcode (NO). When I set Enable Bitcode (No), no more work http service. When I set Enable Bitcode(Yes) the "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" happen. How to solved this error.

Answer (score 0):

How about to use Alamofire instead of SWIFTHttp.
I am using Alamofire with XMPPFRAMEWORK and everything is okay